# .net standard migration for httpcookiecollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Our existing class library project is in .net framework 4.5, now i want to do migrate to .netstandard2.0. I am not sure how we can pass the httpcookiecollection as a parameter in one function for  .netstandard project

Below interface and code from .net framework project

```
public interface IService
    {
        string GetData(string url, HttpCookieCollection oCookies, string Token = null);
    }
```

below code for inheriting the service interface.

```
public class Client: IRestClientService
    {

public string GetDataFromService(string url,  CookieOptions oCookies, string Token=null)
        {
//some code to process the cookie
}

}
```

I have referred below link to work with cookiecollection in .netcore

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-working-with-cookie/

I have installed "Microsoft.AspnetCore.http" but not sure about how to change the httpcookiecollection parameter in interace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the regular `Asp.Net` you was able to read and modify cookie using the same type `HttpCookieCollection`. In `Asp.Net core` you have two different types.

If you need to read cookies as your method's name says you need to use [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IRequestCookieCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.irequestcookiecollection?view=aspnetcore-2.1) from [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features/) package:

```
public interface IService
{
    string GetData(string url, IRequestCookieCollection oCookies, string Token = null);
}
```

If you need to modify cookies you need to use [`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IResponseCookies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iresponsecookies?view=aspnetcore-2.1) from the same package.